# Is it enough to just add localisation .strings files?

Tags: ios, localization, app-store-connect

When localising an iOS app for the AppStore is it enough just to add the translations in the app and translate the .strings files?

Do I have to select anything specific on iTunes Connect also?

I am asking because we have an update ready to go but it is only half translated so I'd like to remove the localisation but not have to mess around with the project files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on whether you want to display on iTunes App Store in more than one language. Please see [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/DisplayInMoreLanguages.html) for more information.